# Problem with importing bibtex-file in a Thesis Template

Tags: bibtex, templates

For my bachelor thesis I downloaded a template made available by my university.
However the standard bibliography part was using

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\end{thebibliography}
```

Since I had already prepared a .bib file for my bibliography I wanted to use that so I tried the following code

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{BachelorBib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

I put my bib-file in the same folder as everything else and I tried putting the code above in the file prepared for the bibliography (which is then included in the main file) and bibtex-compiling that file, I tried just bibtex-compiling the main file. And I tried putting the code above directly in my main file and the bibtex-compiling that main file.

However each time I try to compile my main file to get an output I still don't get my bibliography.

The error-message I get after bibtex-compiling is:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013) The top-level auxiliary file: boek.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: titel.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: voorwoord.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: hoofdstuk1.aux The style file: apalike.bst
A level-1 auxiliary file: referenties.aux Multiple inclusions of entire database
---line 2 of file referenties.aux : \citation{* : }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command Illegal,
another \bibdata command---line 3 of file referenties.aux :
\bibdata : {BachelorBib} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 4 of file referenties.aux :
\bibstyle : {apalike} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: BachelorBib.bib (There were 3 error messages)
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using your commands in reverse order:

```
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}


\bibliographystyle{apalike}    
\bibliography{BachelorBib}
```

I have done in that way and it worked for me. I believe it didn't have anything to do with package which I used. My bibliography style was `ieeetr`. Just give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, putting it in that order in the References.tex file and then including it in the main file worked for me!

Comment: Great to know that it worked for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting all the .aux and .bbl files generated before, leaving only .tex and .bib. Recompile main file *first*, then compile bibtex.

It seems to be like the old `thebibliography` command generated aux files that are not compatible with `\bibliography`.
If that still doesn't work, double check your .bib using some other tool like [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/).